# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python3

Tags: python, docker, shell, dockerfile

I'm getting an error when I try to run a python script `docker build -t my_img .` inside a Dockerfile while building the image:

```dockerfile
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.7.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# setup timezone
RUN echo 'Etc/UTC' > /etc/timezone && \
    ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -q -y --no-install-recommends tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y --reinstall --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    git \
    lsb-release \ 
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    cmake \
    python3-pip python3-dev python-is-python3 \
    zlib1g-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# setup environment
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

## BlenderProc
WORKDIR /root
RUN git clone https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc.git
WORKDIR /root/BlenderProc
RUN pip install -e .

## Download textures
RUN echo 'import blenderproc as bproc' | cat - /root/BlenderProc/blenderproc/scripts/download_cc_textures.py > temp && mv temp /root/BlenderProc/blenderproc/scripts/download_cc_textures.py
RUN python3 /root/BlenderProc/blenderproc/scripts/download_cc_textures.py

ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: What error?  On which line in the Dockerfile?  If it's related to the `download_cc_textures.py` script, what's in that script?

Comment: @DavidMaze [what's in that script?](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc/blob/main/blenderproc/scripts/download_cc_textures.py) , On which line in the Dockerfile --> the unique line that contains `python3`

Comment: I don't see an error message in your posting. Do you really get an error which says _failed to solve ...._?

Comment: @user1934428 the error is posted as a title of my post

Comment: So this means, the error is produced by `docker run`. It means that python3 can't be executed, and I'm surprised that we don't also see the error message produced by `/bin/sh`. I would proceed like this: First check your docker file using a hex editor, whether you have weird characters outside the ASCII range near the RUN python3 command. Then replace the `python3` by a simple `echo`, then by a `ls -l`. If all of this works, use the absolute path to python3. From this, we can then diagnose further the original problem.